# Travis Postgres connection refused

Tags: java, postgresql, travis-ci

I am trying to run tests within a java app which require postgres database.

Below travis.yaml contents

```
sudo: required
language: java
jdk:
  - openjdk11

env:
  global:
    - PGPORT=5432
    - PGHOST=localhost

addons:
  postgresql: "10"
  apt:
    packages:
      - postgresql-10
      - postgresql-client-10

before_script:
  - psql -c 'create database wsboard_test;' -U postgres
  - psql -c "CREATE USER admin WITH PASSWORD 'admin217';" -U postgres


script: mvn clean install -DskipTests=false
```

I am getting psql error

> connection refused

What am I doing wrong? Addon and env setup are taken from the documentation